# How do you deal with database IDs that get astronomically high

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sharding

This question doesn't relate to a problem that I've had (yet), but it keeps me up at night.  Theoretically, eventually, as the number of rows in a table goes up and up and up, the ID corresponding to each row will "run out" of numbers, won't it?  I guess that if you keep adding depth to the column value, you could keep it going up, but eventually there must be an upper limit, right?

I've heard of a technique called "sharding" but haven't had it explained in enough detail to satisfy my curiosity.  Is the answer that you just keep adding more numbers, or is there a clever pattern to allow "repeat" IDs in their own sandbox.  What if these sandboxes have to interact?

Answer (score 5):

Sharding has nothing to do with the size of the IDs.

The correct way to handle it is: Don't worry about it.

A 32 bit int has enough values that you could add one row per second for over 100 years without running out.

And if that wasn't enough, with a 64 bit int you could add 1 *billion* rows per second and still last for over 500 years.

So basically: Don't worry about it. Pick the size of the int based on how many rows you expect times 100 and then move on.

Re sharding:

That's simply a way of splitting up a database onto multiple servers by using a rule to decide which server should get the data. The rules vary depending on what you are storing and how many servers you have.

Comment: "Don't worry about it" - I honestly hope that big corporations such as Google don't have that attitude... "Sorry guys - we can't crawl any more websites - we've hit our id limit." :P

Comment: @shadow Yes, don't worry about it. Google can use a 64 bit int and not have to think about it again for billions of years. Do you realize just how big a 64 bit int is? There are companies that have hit the limit on a 32 bit int - twitter for example. But none have ever maxed out a 64 bit int.

Comment: I know - I posted about BIGINT just before... but I'm sure they don't have a "don't worry about it" attitude. I agree that it is high. But think about how many searches are done on Google every second (for arguments sake). It's not impossible. Just insanely unlikely.

Comment: @shadow At the current rate of searching google, a 64 bit int is enough for 10 million years. Even if search traffic DRAMATICALLY increases, it's still enough. In contrast a 32 bit int would last them about 1 day. You simply have to know your estimated size and plan accordingly. (Or change the size once you get big.)

Comment: Shadow is right that it's not impossible - we are heading towards larger and larger numbers.  For now 64 bit is enough, but hopefully Intel or whoever can have 128 bit architecture working by the time we need bigger numbers.  Then when that's not enough, 256, then 512, etc.

Comment: @andrewb To count to a 128 bit number using a quantum computer would require enough energy to boil all of the worlds oceans. Using an ordinary computer? Forget it, I doubt there is enough energy in the solar system to do that. We will never need 256 bit numbers for use as IDs. (They could be used for other things, but for IDs they will never be necessary.)

Comment: @shadow and andrewb See: https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/128_bit_storage_are_you

Comment: @andrewb To count to a 256 bit number you would need a computer 2000 times larger than the entire milky way: [See here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^256+bits+%2F+10^31+bits%2Fkg) To count to a 512 bit number you would need 4 * 10^70 times the mass of the entire universe!

Answer (score 2):

From [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

> Use a large enough integer data type for the AUTO_INCREMENT column to hold the maximum sequence value you will need. When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next attempt to generate a sequence number fails. For example, if you use TINYINT, the maximum permissible sequence number is 127. For TINYINT UNSIGNED, the maximum is 255.

That's actually fascinating. I guess an easy (semi) answer is to use BIGINT - with a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. If you get that many columns - then... wow...